# HTML absolute element interact with window bounds

Tags: html, css

I created a sample to show my problem: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jervin93/2o16Ly7g/11/)

I am using an absolute element (it has auto width and height) and I set it's position from javascript (style.left and style.top specifically), the problem is it is interacting with the browser window's bounds. As you see in the example the buttons are not positioned horizontally (if you can't see try to press the run button), because it is near to the window's right bound..

How can I solve this? I don't want this interaction, I want the buttons horizontally at any position, if it is near the bound then clip the invisible part like this:

[image]

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
  <button>
  First
  </button>
  <button>
  Second
  </button>
  <button>
  Third
  </button>
  <button>
  Quad
  </button>  
</div>
    
</body>
</html>



#container{
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  left: 0;
  right: auto;
}


window.onload=() => {
  const container=document.getElementById("container");
  container.style.left= (window.innerWidth-75)+"px";
}
```

Comment: if you want set buttons at any position, you must add `position: absolute` to buttons, not container.
Am I understand your question?

Comment: please send an image from paint or photoshop and draw what you want!

Comment: I added an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
window.onload=() => {
  const container=document.getElementById("container");
  container.style.left= (window.innerWidth-75)+"px";
}
```

```css
#container{

  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  left: 0;
  right: auto;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>



<div id="container">
  <button>
  First
  </button>
  <button>
  Second
  </button>
  <button>
  Third
  </button>
  <button>
  Quad
  </button>  
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

- add `display: flex;` on `#container` class

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox to make a column, it's realy powerful, flex-direction property make all childs in a column and display flex is needed to use flex-direction.

```
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  left: 0;
  right: auto;
}
```